# Spring Boot and JavaScript: How to access a promise object field?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot

I am a JavaScript novice.
I need your help please to understand what is wrong here...

I use Spring Boot for beck-end.

I defined a REST API which returns a MatchStats Object:

```
public class MatchStats {
    
    private int homeScore;
    private int awayScore;
    private Map<Player, Integer> homePlayersScore;
    private Map<Player, Integer> awayPlayersScore;

    public MatchStats() {
    }

    ...
    
    //getters...
    
}
```

Player is an Entity mapping a DB table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    ...
    
    //getters...
    
}
```

I validated on the **BE side** that the returned MatchStats object is totally valid!

However, on the FE JavaScript function, after calling this API it seems that I don't know how to access the player name field in the returned promise object.

I always receive 'undefined' value.

When I log the received MatchStats object in console, I see for the maps the following output:

```
Object
    HomePlayersScore
        com.ttt.bbsim.model.Player@6bed93f: 1
        com.ttt.bbsim.model.Player@6c1a2709: 11
        com.ttt.bbsim.model.Player@7a79be06: 15
        ...
```

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(player)); gives me:

```
(36) ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "length"]
```

What does it mean?

My latest javascript code is as follows:

```
let response = await fetch(apiCall);
var matchStats = await response.json();
console.log(matchStats); // looks good in console

for (const [player, score] of Object.entries(matchStats.homePlayersScore)) {

    console.log(typeof player); // **gives me a String type for some reason!!!**

    console.log("player: " + player + " score: " + score); 
    // player is undefined. I also tried player.name and player[name] but no use..
```

What is the way to access the player name field?

Thanks!

Comment: JSON only maps string keys to values, so even though Javascript has a Map data structure your map doesn't survive the trip. I'm guessing that when you serialize on the backend the Player key is being automagically converted to its string representation and is unsurprisingly a string on the frontend. You will likely either need to rethink your data representations or write some custom serialization/deserialization logic.

Comment: Thank you Jared. I will think on other options. If you got a suggestion for me I will be grateful! I still wonder why, when I expand the map object in console it looks like <player object reference -- score> pairs, and not <string -- score> as you explained. Like I showed in the question: <com.ttt.bbsim.model.Player@6bed93f: 1> , etc. But maybe I didn't understand well..

Comment: Yes, without a doubt sending only the name string as the map key instead of the complete Player object worked. But of course it is the unwanted design. I wish there was some solution to my requirement.